# ストアドプロシージャの実行結果とJOINしたい

Tags: mysql

MYSQLでストアドを実行するときは`CALL ストアド名(引数...);`のように書きますが、
この結果と他のテーブルをJOINってできたりしますか？
もちろん、単純に下記のように書くとエラーになります。
他の書き方で、できたりするのでしょうか？
※「ストアドで全てやれ！！」、「一時テーブルを使用しろ！！」の突っ込みはなしでお願いします。

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  テーブルA AT
  LEFT JOIN (CALL ストアド名(引数...)) ST
  ON 条件..
```

Comment: できないでしょう。Postgresqlならできるのにね。

Comment: MYSQLはできないのですね...ありがとうございます！！

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MYSQLではストアドの結果にJOINはできない！！